# Check if ast.Expr Implements Interface in Go

Tags: go, interface, abstract-syntax-tree, analyzer

Is there any way we can check if any `ast.Expr` is implementing `interface` like `fmt.Stringer`?

I found this function `types.Implements()` can be used here but, I am not sure how I can create `types.Interface` out of an existing `interface` type, like `fmt.Stringer`, which is required for `types.Implements()` function.

I am looking for a function implementation like this:

```
func isStringer(ti *types.Info, obj ast.Expr) bool {
    panic("not implemented")
}
```

Workaround I am using currently:

```
func isStringer(ti *types.Info, obj ast.Expr) bool {
    t := ti.TypeOf(obj).(*types.Named)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethods(); i++ {
        if t.Method(i).Type().(*types.Signature).String() == "func() string" {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: This example is using `reflect` package, and I want to get the same from `types` package which is not compatible with `reflect`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way I check if an interface is implemented is by using a long form [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)

Ex:

```golang
func isStringer(obj ast.Expr) bool {
    _, ok := obj.(fmt.Stringer)
    return ok
}
```

What's going on here is that when we provide a second variable to the type assertion (usually named `ok` by convention), go will not panic if the type cannot be cast, instead it will set `ok = false`.

We can then simply return the value of `ok` and be assured that if `ok == true` the `obj` implements stringer and if `ok == false` it does not.

If we want to use the methods provided by the stringer interface, we can return the cast variable as well:

```golang
func isStringer(obj ast.Expr) (fmt.Stringer, bool) {
    return obj.(fmt.Stringer)
}
```